# flex 4 Paddings,ScrollPolicy,borderAlpha,backgroundColor errors

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flash-builder

i have the folowing inicial code:

```
<s:TitleWindow xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                width="800"
                textAlign="left"
                paddingLeft="0"
                paddingTop="0"
                paddingRight="0"
                paddingBottom="0"
                borderAlpha="1"
                verticalScrollPolicy="off"
                horizontalScrollPolicy="off"
                creationComplete="creationComplete(event)"
                backgroundColor="{FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.canvasBackgroundColor}">
```

I have errors in the Paddings,ScrollPolicy,borderAlpha and backgroundColor like this

**Cannot resolve attribute '...' for component type spark.components.TitleWindow.**
is there a quick way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ScrollPolicy is a style setting:

```
<fx:Style>
    @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";

    s|TitleWindow #scroller {
        horizontalScrollPolicy: off;
        verticalScrollPolicy: off;
    }
</fx:Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it cannot resolve the attribute it means that attribute is not available for that component. Do a search for adding padding to spark components.

Try adding a layout to the TitleWindow:

```
<s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout paddingLeft="10" paddingRight="10" paddingTop="10" paddingBottom="10" />
    </s:layout>
```

B

Comment: Yes that resolve the paddings,and i add -theme=${flexlib}/themes/Spark/spark.css to the console to fix the background and alpha problem, the only thing left is the ScrollPolicy that i cant find the answer